# DataTables Custom Search in Laravel

Tags: laravel, datatables

I'm using laravel to create a contact page, and this is my view code:

```
<table id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="no-sort"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php $idx = 1; ?>
        @foreach($users as $result)
            @if($idx == 1) <tr> @endif
            <td class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 animated fadeInDown">
                <div class="well profile_view">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <h4 class="brief"><i>Digital Strategist</i></h4>
                        <div class="left col-xs-7">
                            <h2>{!! $result->first_name !!}</h2>
                            <p><strong>Username: </strong> {!! $idx !!} </p>
                            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                <li>{!! $result->email !!}</li>

                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="right col-xs-5 text-center">
                            @if($result->image)
                                {!! Html::image('packages/calibre/images/profile/'.$result->image, '', array("class"=>"img-circle img-responsive")) !!}
                            @else
                                {!! Html::image('packages/calibre/images/profile/none.png', '', array("class"=>"img-circle img-responsive")) !!}
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 bottom text-center">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 emphasis">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs pull-left"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Active</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-right"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> View Profile </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            @if($idx == 3) </tr> @endif
            <?php if($idx == 3) $idx = 1; else $idx++; ?>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

the layout is not like common tables, it's using  tag from it's template.

How to enable it using DataTables to search and paging? anyone could help me?

Comment: Just a tip, if you remove some of the classes it's easier to read so we don't have to sift through all the `col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12`

Comment: Is this what you are talking about? Have you read through these docs? https://www.datatables.net/